# Поток и событие класса, затрагивающее VCL-компоненту

Tags: delphi, vcl

Пишу в Delphi 2010.
Есть `TVirtualStringTree`.
 Есть класс `TExample`, порожденный от `TList<T>`, где данные `TVirtualStringTree` и хранятся. 
Так же `TExample` описанно событие `OnNotify`, чтоб дерево показывало данные.

```
procedure TExample.OnNotifyTaskCommList(Sender: TObject;
  const Item: PRecord; Action: TCollectionNotification);
begin
  if Assigned(FVST) then
    FVST.RootNodeCount := self.Count; // в лоб
//TDoMainThread.Create(ChangeNodeCount).Start; // Версия №1
//SendMessage(FormHandle, MESS_1, WPARAM(AControl), self.Count); // Версия №2

end;
```

Но дело в том, что с `TExample` работает поток.
 Т.к. `TExample` не VCL, то и `Synchronize` я не делаю в том потоке. 
НО! 
Ведь в событии дергается свойство VCL компонента.  
Понимаю, что надо обойти это, но не хочется вешать `Synchronize` на процедуру добавления, удаления записи. Всего то надо изменить кол-во нод. 
Появились идеи:
1) использовать дополнительный класс от `TThread` с пустым `Execute`. 
Типо такого:

```
constructor TDoMainThread.Create(Event: TNotifyEvent);
begin
  inherited Create(True);
  FreeOnTerminate := true;
  Priority        := tplowest;
  Synchronize(self, procedure begin
    Event(self);
  end);
end;
```

где `Event` - это процедура изменения нод. И только она выполнится в главном потоке.
2) использовать сообщения, но для этого классу надо будет еще передать и хэндл формы, и номер сообщения. Прям под зависимость попадаем.

Как лучше исполнить этот обход?

Comment: передавайте сообщение сразу дереву, или возьмите хэндл его владельца, это и будет форма.

Comment: Я думал на счет передачи сообщения дереву, но как? Это надо будет создавать класс от TVirtualStringTree, где определить message для этого действия. И форма в моем случае не владелец, а владелец фрейм.

Comment: Вы не путаете VLC и VCL случайно? Первое - это плеер. Второе - это Visual Component Library в Делфе. Исправьте вопрос (кнопка "править")

Comment: Да, благодарю :) Исправил. Даже с такой опечаткой программисты меня поняли

Answer (score 0):

В общем, ничего лучшего пока не придумал, как сделать так:

```
procedure TExample.OnNotifyTaskCommList(Sender: TObject;
  const Item: PRecord; Action: TCollectionNotification);
begin
  if (Action in [cnRemoved, cnExtracted]) and Assigned(Item) then
    DisposeAndNill(Item);
  if Assigned(FVST) then
    TThread.Synchronize(nil, ChangeNodeCount); // даже не создаю поток, а использую его метод
end;
```

Upd: Залез в класс TVirtualStringTree и добавил там методы

```
  private
    // [ME_COMMENT] Эти ф-ии я ввел сам
    procedure RootNodeCount_MSG(var Msg: TMessage);  message MESS_SET_ROOTNODECOUNT;
    procedure ChileNodeCount_MSG(var Msg: TMessage); message MESS_SET_CHILDNODECOUNT;

  public
    // [ME_COMMENT] Эти ф-ии я ввел сам
    procedure RootNodeCount_SM(Count: Cardinal);
    procedure ChileNodeCount_SM(Node: PVirtualNode; Count: Cardinal);
```

Добавил константы:

```
Const
// [ME_COMMENT] добавил сам для
  MESS_SET_ROOTNODECOUNT  = WM_USER + 1;
  MESS_SET_CHILDNODECOUNT = WM_USER + 2;
```

И реализация:

```
procedure TVirtualStringTree.RootNodeCount_MSG(var Msg: TMessage);  // MESS_SET_ROOTNODECOUNT;
begin
  RootNodeCount := Msg.LParam;
end;

procedure TVirtualStringTree.ChileNodeCount_MSG(var Msg: TMessage); // MESS_SET_CHILDNODECOUNT;
begin
  ChildCount[PVirtualNode(Msg.WParam)] := Msg.LParam;
end;

procedure TVirtualStringTree.RootNodeCount_SM(Count: Cardinal);
begin
  SendMessage(Handle, MESS_SET_ROOTNODECOUNT, 0, Count);
end;

procedure TVirtualStringTree.ChileNodeCount_SM(Node: PVirtualNode; Count: Cardinal);
begin
  SendMessage(Handle, MESS_SET_CHILDNODECOUNT, WPARAM(Node), Count);
end;
```

Но лезть в чужой класс - это в крайнем случае и неочень правильно.

upd:
Попытался решить вопрос с помощью хелпер-а

```
const
  MESS_SET_ROOTNODECOUNT  = WM_USER + 100;
type
THelperForVST = class helper for TVirtualStringTree
  private
    procedure RootNodeCount_MSG(var Msg: TMessage);  message MESS_SET_ROOTNODECOUNT;
  public
    procedure RootNodeCount_SM(Count: Cardinal);
  end;

//--------------------------------
procedure THelperForVST.RootNodeCount_MSG(var Msg: TMessage);  // MESS_SET_ROOTNODECOUNT;
begin
  RootNodeCount := Msg.LParam;
  TopNode       := GetLast();
end;
//--------------------------------
procedure THelperForVST.RootNodeCount_SM(Count: Cardinal);
begin
  SendMessage(Handle, MESS_SET_ROOTNODECOUNT, 0, Count);
end;
//--------------------------------
```

Метод появился. Передаю сообщение, а реакции нет. В дебагере даже брекпоинт на RootNodeCount_MSG(var Msg: TMessage) нельзя поставить. Короче, нельзя так сделать для хэлпера.

Comment: Primož Gabrijelčič в своих книжках описывает созданный им класс [TCommThread](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Delphi-High-Performance/blob/master/Chapter%206/DHPThreads.pas) который разработан с целью упрощения организации обмена сообщениями между потоками и гуем. Можете посмотреть на него в деле.

Comment: Лезть в чужой класс **очень** не правильно. Кто вам мешает добавить эти события в ваш фрейм, который владеет деревом и уже оттуда вызывать метод SetChildCount у дерева?

Comment: Я писал, что неочень правильно. Ваше предложение норм, но есть минусы. Это 1) нужно для каждого фрейма вводить данную процедуру с SendMessage. 2) эту процедуру надо передавать в класс TExample, т.е. включить ее в конструктор. Т.е. кроме самого VST еще и процедуру изменения кол-ва нод этого VST. Нагромождения.

Comment: А в Delphi 2010 class hepler'ов ещё нет? Самое оно для таких вещей.

Comment: Да, очень хорошее решение. А я даже и не знал про такую фитчу. Поизучал. Советуют поосторожнее с хэлперами, но в данном случае норм :)